# Common function for classes derived from a class template

Tags: c++, templates

I have a program with the following class hierarchy:

```cpp
struct TYPE_ONE { int i; };
struct TYPE_TWO { int i; };

template<typename T>
class Base
{
        public:
                int fun(int i);

};

template<typename T>
int Base<T>::fun(int i)
{
        return 42 * i;
}


class A : public Base<TYPE_ONE>
{
        public:
                void another_fun()
                {
                        fun(1);
                }
} a;

class B : public Base<TYPE_TWO>
{
        public:
                void another_fun()
                {
                        fun(2);
                }

} b;

int main()
{
        a.another_fun();
        b.another_fun();
}
```

As you can see the `fun` doesn't depend on the type. Unfortunately compiler is generating two `fun` methods. One for each type.

```
$ nm --demangle ./a.out | grep fun
0000000000001150 W A::another_fun()
0000000000001174 W B::another_fun()
0000000000001198 W Base<TYPE_ONE>::fun(int)
00000000000011b0 W Base<TYPE_TWO>::fun(int)
```

Is there a way to force compiler to generate only one common function for both classes?

I see that I could try to workaround this by making `fun` static and adding default argument to the template. Something like:

```cpp
template<typename T=TYPE_ONE>
class Base
{
        public:
                static int fun(int i);

};

class A : public Base<TYPE_ONE>
{
        public:
                void another_fun()
                {
                        Base<>::fun(1);
                }
} a;

class B : public Base<TYPE_TWO>
{
        public:
                void another_fun()
                {
                        Base<>::fun(2);
                }

} b;
```

With this compiler generates only one `fun` method:

```
$ nm --demangle ./a.out | grep fun
0000000000001150 W A::another_fun()
000000000000116e W B::another_fun()
000000000000118c W Base<TYPE_ONE>::fun(int)
```

But is there a cleaner solution for this issue?

Comment: in your example, `fun` actually has nothing to do with the class whatsoever. I would just make it a free function.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox in real code it operates on class members. But I can workaround it by passing pointers to it. Key issue for me is reducing code usage.

Comment: Members of what class? `Base`? Then you can move it (and the members) to a non-template base of `Base`.

Comment: So what is happening here is that we are guessing what you are trying to do based on this contrived example. You need to make the example much closer to the real one. Also you need to explain why you care that the code is generated twice. It will also be generated for every translation unit. Is that a problem?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Looks like your suggestion can be the solution. I can't move members to the base of `Base` as they depend on `T`. But moving `fun` there and passing members by a pointer makes compiler not generating additional code. Thanks!

Comment: if your `fun` doesn't really require to use template class, you can write it in a base class with no templates at all. You may name it as `Base` and rename the actual `Base` to `BaseT` which inherit from `Base` (just to give an example)

Answer (score 3):

The following defines two distinct types, that happen to have exactly the same implementation:

```
struct TYPE_ONE { int i; };
struct TYPE_TWO { int i; };
```

This misleads to think that `fun()` should share the same code.

But in reality,  this is a very exceptional circumstance. Because the two types could share a symbol `i` with a different memory layout, that would require a different machine code to perform the apparently identical i*42.

```
struct TYPE_ONE { int i; };
struct TYPE_TWO { int k,i; };
```

You could even have the case of different types, where again, the machine code would be completely different and could not be shared:

```
struct TYPE_ONE { int i; };
struct TYPE_TWO { double i; };
```

Of course, the compiler could recognize that the types have an identical layout and make the effort of using some common code. But it's not at all an obligation.

If there is a common part in the template class with fixed types, you should refactor that common part into a non-template base to the template class.  For example:

```
struct RealBase { 
    int i;
    int fun(int i); 
}; 

struct TYPE_ONE : RealBase {}; 
struct TYPE_TWO : RealBase {};
```

and adapt A and B accordingly.  Here there is one RealBase, whatever template you build upon it.  And your compiler would naturally have only one RealBase implementation.